# looking for a vlookup subtracting from multiple cells or something better

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula that can subtract `501 WIP DATE` from `501 ISSUE DATE`, 3 columns A,B,C:

```
item    item type   date    
501      wip        07/11/17    
501      issue      07/16/17    
502      wip        07/15/17    
502      issue      07/15/17
```

Comment: Cindy, your question is not very clear. See [this help topic](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If all you want to do is subtract the date in C2 from the one in C3, you can just enter `=C3-C2` in cell D3.  If it's more than that, you need to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you fill in more of the details?  Is this a one time problem concerning only item 501, a general need to do this for every item, or do you specify 501 somewhere (where?) and need to lookup a result for whatever is specified?  Are item types limited to wip and issue and does every item have exactly those two records?  Is all data complete or do you need to handle missing data?  Are the item records always together and always in the wip, issue sequence or do you need to identify the item type for each record (and/or find the records)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to calculate elapsed days, you can use this formula, as demonstrated in the screenshot:

```
=IF([@[item type]]="issue",INDEX([date],MATCH([@item]&[@[item type]],INDEX([item]&[item type],0),0))-INDEX([date],MATCH([@item]&"wip",INDEX([item]&[item type],0),0)),"")
```

I used an Excel table with structured references, but you can use A1 notation, too. Just don't use this approach with whole columns, because it will be slow to recalculate.

[image]

Comment: this helped a lot but one thing I forgot was to subtract weekends.

Comment: use Networkdays() instead of subtraction. The first Index/Match finds the issue date, the second Index/Match finds the wip date. Plug these into the Networkdays function.